# phpExcel Read in chunks so slow and memory errors

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to read a big excel file of about 20mb to import into mysql.

I've searched across internet and found the "Chunks reading" solution, however is not working... or is SO slowly for me, and I'm not sure why.

This is what im doing:

```
// .....
// into MyReadFilter class.. this is the most important function:
public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        //  Only read the rows and columns that were configured
        if (($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->_startRow && $row < $this->_endRow)) {
            if (in_array($column,$this->_columns)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
// .....


$filter = new MyReadFilter(1, 22000); 
$chunkSize = 10;

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setReadFilter($filter);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(false); //not sure if this should be true


for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 65536; $startRow += $chunkSize) {

  echo "Reading";
  $filterSubset->setRows($startRow, $chunkSize);
  $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); // this line takes like 40 seconds... for 10 rows?
  echo "chunk done! ";
}
```

However, inside the for, the $objReader->load() is taking like 40 seconds, and in fact, after 2 loops I got a memory error.

If I unset the $objReader inside the for I can make it run about 20 times inside the for... (although it take like 10 minutes) and.. memory error.

I'm wondering why the load function seems to read all the file if im using a filter, also the filter strategy seems to parse all rows and return false for all rows that are not being required... is not posible to abort reading or really read just the required ones?

I've tried a couple of FilterClass and code snippets but got same results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You're using a filter, then the Reader is still reading the whole file but only populating the PHPExcel object cells that are defined by the filter; and the Reader still needs to read the whole file each pass of the filtering process, which is what makes it slower.

The Reader needs to read the whole file because of the structure of the raw spreadsheet files. Cell data is not stored with cell formatting, and cell content may also be stored separately. The Reader needs to pull all this together. You can't simply abort the reader when the filter condition is met, because the reader has no way of knowing that it has been completed... if you have a filter that is limiting the load to cells A1:C3, then you can't abort after B3 has been read because you don't know if cell B2 comes after that in the file, or there may be comments associated with cell A1 further on in the file. Until the whole file has been loaded and parsed, you can't start to filter.

The main memory usage in PHPExcel is the PHPExcel object, and specifically the cells (typically about 1k/cell on 32-bit PHP).... the main solution provided to reduce memory here is cell caching. This can (using SQLite caching) reduce cell memory usage to 0k/cell, though at a cost in speed.

The Reader doesn't use much more memory than the size of the Excel file (decompressed) itself, so is normally far less of a memory problem; but this is being addressed (for XML-based spreadsheet formats) by switching from SimpleXML to XMLReader. But it is dependent on the format of the file being loaded; xls format files are very different to xlsx files (xlsx will benefit from this, xls won't) and also dependent on the developers being able to find the time to do this - but it is on the roadmap for the coming year, and work has already started.

Comment: Ok, after hours and hours spent on this i decided to do save as CSV and the import was done in couple of minutes..

Comment: Thanks for explaining this Mark, I was unsure why the filters were structured the way they are as I thought "wow this is inefficient, having to check every cell". What you have said makes it clear as to why it is designed like this.